# quick preview animation with animated material?

Tags: rendering, animation, materials, opengl

I am looking for a poor man's render of an animation in order to evaluate blocking, timing, camera movements etc. without the "cost" of a full render.
I found [Is there a way to make a quick animation PREVIEW, to evaluate motion, etc.?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47774/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-quick-animation-preview-to-evaluate-motion-etc) and thus tried OpenGL render with "Material" view (and for more speed also used a reduced render image size).

In principle, this would be good enough for me - at this stage I do not care about transparency, light, or hdri background. However, I do have **animated material**, and that animation is lost but should please end up in the rendered preview movie.

In fact, this loss is not a problem of the animation *render*, but happens already in the normal 3D preview. I recall that *sometimes* the material gets adjusted in the view but in a somewhat unpredictable manner (e.g., it is not simply the state at frame 1). So instead of proposals about a completely different rendering method, I'd also be happy with a way to make the material view adhere to animated material.

---

Additional info: I am on blender 2.76 (I know it's not current, but that's the default on Ubuntu Xenial, which is also not current, but still under LTS until next year)